# How to write: There exists $A$ for $f(x)$ such that $A$ always equals $0$ for which $f(x)$ is not undefined?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

How can I state the following in mathematical symbols:
There exists $A$ for $f(x)$ such that $A$ always equals $0$ for which $f(x)$ is not undefined?

I have come up with

$$\exists\ A_{f(x)}:A=0\ ,\ f(x)\notin\emptyset$$

but is it proper to equate something being undefined as being in the empty set? Is there a better way to convey this; for example, would $\forall\ {f(x)}: \exists\ {A}$ (i.e., for all $f(x)$ where $f(x)$ yields a value $A$ which is defined (i.e., where it exists)?

Comment: Can you, please, specify what $A$ actually is? Is it just some value from $\mathcal{D}_f$, or..?

Comment: It is not at all clear what you mean.  But if $f$ is a function, "$f(x)$ is undefined" just means that $x$ is not in the domain of $f$.

Comment: Your question is about three things: $A$, $f$ and $x$, but the dependencies amongst these three things are unclear. Your use of $f(x)$ suggests that $f$ is a function. Whether $f(x)$ is defined will depend on what $f$ is and what $x$ is. Your statement that $A = 0$ implies that $A$ is just a number, independent of $f$ and $x$.  And certainly $f(x) \not\in\emptyset$ does not mean that $f(x)$ is undefined.

Comment: To clarify the relationship between $A$, $f$, and $x$, $$A=\int_{-\varepsilon}^{\varepsilon}f(x)\ dx$$
where $f$ is a function of variable $x$.
I guess the question to which the above statement would be applicable is: Does $A$ always equal $0$ for $f(x)$ where the function is not undefined over the interval $-\varepsilon$ to $\varepsilon$ (i.e., where $f(x)$ is defined?

Comment: Before stating this in symbols, you should first state it more clearly in English.